# SLComposeViewController - read only

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, slcomposeviewcontroller

**Problem**

I'm trying to provide my users with an alternative to purchasing my iAP by allowing them to share that they're playing the game via facebook.

However, when the composer view controller loads the content is editable by the user. Which, for profitability sake is a bad thing. They could remove the entire message and still receive the perk that they receive for sharing. Thus, ruling out that way of marketing.

I'm curious as to two solutions.

**Solution One**

Force Read-Only ?

**Solution Two**

Cancel the sharing and display an error message if the sent message is not equal to the initial text/images.

Also, if it is not possible for them to remove the image and/or url then I don't really have a problem with them adding their own text. However, if they can remove the image/url then there is an issue.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Restricting/enforcing what to share by the user, in any way, is not allowed in the Facebook Platform Policy. See also point 2 of: https://developers.facebook.com/policy#control. You can't make the share dialog read-only and you should not check if they shared the content you have provided.

With the second solution; you might also be hitting a policy restriction. You should not incentivize people to share in order for these kind of promotions. See rule number 5: https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse. This might be an more difficult issue though, policy wise.

You can let people share an open graph object; either generated from your app or directly one that you (or FB) is hosting, with an open graph url. For that, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices.